# Parsing filename to get datetime with powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

I've filename sample `backup_2014_05_14_020001_0111095.bak`.
How to get `DateTime` from this sample with powershell scripting?

I tried something like this:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem | 
Sort-Object { [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName,'\Te\s\t\-yyyyMMdd\-HHmm',$null) } |
Select-Object -Last 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try :

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact("backup_2014_05_14_020001",'backup_yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss',$null)
```

So in you case you just have to trunk `$_.BaseName`

```
"backup_2014_05_14_020001_0111095.bak".Substring(0,24)
```

At the end :

```
$file = Get-ChildItem | 
Sort-Object { [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName.Substring(0,24),'backup_yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss',$null) } |
Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: You can simplify the parse with ($_.BaseName.Substring(7,17),'yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss',$null)